# Automatically apply Semantic UI on arbitrary asynchronous templates

Tags: javascript, semantic-ui

I am test driving Semantic UI and I was curious if I could automatically apply the UI components behaviours on dynamically added HTML templates?

Example :

```
getTemplateHTML(url).then(function (html) {

   $(someElement).html(html);

   // apply behaviours to $(someElement)'s content
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add SUI component's initialization code to any callback that you receive after rendering your dynamic template.
If you are talking about Meteor, than you should use template `onRendered` callback, as I've answered in [Access HTML after this.render() in Iron Router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31643674/access-html-after-this-render-in-iron-router)