# Access HTML after this.render() in Iron Router

Tags: jquery, meteor, iron-router, semantic-ui

I need to apply some Semantic UI on newly rendered templates, but I have no idea how to get the rendered HTML from the router. Here's my code :

```
Router.route('/', {
  name: 'home',

  where: 'client',

  action: function () {

    this.render('home');
  },

  onAfterAction: function () {

    console.log( $('#homeSidebar') );

  }

});
```

Basically, `$('#homeSidebar')` should return the sidebar element, but it returns nothing as the HTML is not yet available. The only solution, so far, was to change the function like this

```
  onAfterAction: function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
      $('#homeSidebarToggle').on('click', function () {
        $('#homeSidebar').sidebar('toggle');
      });
    }, 200);    
  }
```

Which is neither clean nor safe. How can I run a function immediately as soon as the HTML is availble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `onRendered` callback on the template. Meteor uses template `helpers, events and callbacks` for manipulating DOM. Iron Router is just for routing)
Your client/view.html:

```
<template name="home">
  <div id="homeSidebar">

  </div>
</template>
```

Your client/view.js:

```
Template.home.onRendered(function () {
  console.log($('#homeSidebar'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't upvote this, as I consider your answer incomplete. If I'm asking questions, it is because I have read, and tried things in the first place and, confused, I'm expecting thorough answer. First, `onRendered`, where do I use this? Also, "Read the docs" is not an answer in this case.

Comment: Thank you! With this example, `onRendered` seems to be exactly what I need.

Answer (score 3):

You can look at [tracker.afterFlush](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/tracker_afterflush) to schedule code to run after all invalidated computations have been dealt with.

However your specific example looks like a common case of a jQuery developer coming into Meteor and just applying jQuery patterns directly. Usually in Meteor there's an easier way.

A simpler and better way to attach an event handler to a template is with [template events](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_events). In your case:

```
Template.home.events({
  'click #homeSidebarToggle': function(ev){
    $('#homeSidebar').sidebar('toggle');
  }
});
```